# Just transferred project to a different computer, content_my.xml and activity_my.xml missing

Tags: android-studio

I just transferred one of my projects in Android Studio from one computer to another. Now the files **content_my.xml** and **activity_my.xml** are not showing up in the editor. Instead there is an **ApplicationTest.java** file.

To transfer the files all I did was go to `USER/[me]/Androidstudioprojects` and copied the desired file to a flashdrive. Put it in the same place on my desktop then opened Android Studio and ran the `build.gradle`

This is what the ApplicationTest.java file contains:

```
package com.example.[me].[project];

import android.app.Application;
import android.test.ApplicationTestCase;

/**
 * <a href="http://d.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html">Testing Fundamentals</a>
 */
public class ApplicationTest extends ApplicationTestCase<Application> {
    public ApplicationTest() {
        super(Application.class);
    }
}
```

I'm still really new to android studio and would love to have my old files back.

Comment: Did you close and reopen the project properly after you moved it around? Did you check in the file explorer if the files you are looking for are actually there? It is hard to believe that ApplicationTest.java would simply spawn out of nowhere.

Comment: Okay I opened the project in Android studio on the original computer I was using and it's the same situation for some reason. All there is is this ApplicationTest file which I have no idea how to use. The only .xml file I have is AndroidManifest.xml. I also searched the project file for these .xml's that I need and nothing shows up. It's harder to believe that these files would just disappear out of nowhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh man, I goofed up big time guys. 
The file path in the editor for the *content_.xml* and *activity_.xml* is res/layout/. I was looking in the wrong place. I'm a little slow today I guess.

Comment: No worries, happens to everyone :)
Sometimes we just need to take a step back and rethink the situation.